# FormName.Show won't work

Tags: .net, winforms

When I try to show a form, I have to use ShowDialog instead of Show.  (This is causing problems later in my code.)  When I use show, the form pops up for a second and then the program closes. (VB.Net 2003)

Answer (score 1):

Use `Application.Run()` after showing your form so the application can continue working.

Or use `Application.Run(yourForm)` which will show your form and keep the application running until the `yourForm` closes.

Comment: After days of searching the web and finding answers that don't work,this works - and it's so simple!  Thank you!

Comment: Be aware that if you call `Application.Run()`, you will have to explicitly stop the application by calling `Application.Exit()` when your form closes, like in the `Form_Closed` event.